# How to let Eclipse manage .properties and .xml file

Tags: eclipse

I have a bunch of .properties file and .xml files. Can I comment/uncomment some part of such files quickly under Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the structured text editors (eg. XML editor)  , the default hot-keys that comment ,uncomment and toggle comment for the selected lines are :

- Comment  : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- Uncomment  : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>
- Toggle Comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

For the properties file editor , the default hot-key to toggle comments is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

You can configure all of them in the **Preferences --> General --> Keys** .Type "Comment" in the filter to filter out the hot-keys about comment.

Comment: how u open the .properties file with the `properties file editor`  and then use the keys CTRL+/ ??